# Question about square roots

Tags: logic

The roots of, let's say 4, can be either 2 or -2. Why is this an inclusive-or *i.e.* if $x^2 = 4$, then $x = 2 \vee x = −2$, instead of an exclusive-or *i.e.* if $x^2 = 4$, then $x = 2 \oplus x = −2$? It can only be one of them because we can only get 4 if we do a $2 \times 2$ or a $-2 \times -2$. From my understanding, something that can only be one or the other, should be treated as an exclusive-or.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is an exclusive or. Why do you say it is an inclusive or? If it was an inclusive or there would be the possibility that $x$ equals two different values at the same time.

Comment: @Shahab Ah, because when I answered a quiz in https://www.coursera.org/course/maththink, I said that it should be an exclusive-or because, as you said, there is no possibility that $x$ equals two different values. But I got the wrong answer and I'm not quite sure why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, the notation $x = (2 \vee -2)$ does not make any sense. Do you mean $x = 2 \vee x = -2$? Also, note that the square root $\sqrt{a}$ is defined to be the **positive** solution of $x^2 =a $, so $\sqrt 4 \neq -2$.

Now while it is true that $x = 2$ and $x = -2$ can never be true at the same time, the situation changes if we have a quadratic equation with a double solution, e.g., $x^2 = 0$. This equation has solutions $x = 0$ and $x = -0$, but since $0 = -0$, $x = 0 \oplus x = -0$ does not hold. This is why it is preferable to use an inclusive or.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that case!

Answer (score 3):

This confusion would all cease if we referred to the $\sqrt{\,\cdot\,}$ symbol as '*flobble*' rather than '*square root*', since a positive real number $a$ has two square roots and $\sqrt{a}$ refers to only one of them. (The other is $-\sqrt{a}$.)

If $x=\sqrt{4}$ then $x=2$, not $-2$, since $\sqrt{4}$ refers exclusively* to the positive square root.

I'm not sure what $x = (2 \oplus -2)$ is meant to mean. If it means $x=2$ xor $x=-2$ as Shahab suggests in the comments, then... well let me explain. It's true that **if** $x^2 = 4$ **then** ($x = 2$ xor $x=-2$); but it is not true that $\sqrt{4} = 2$ xor $-2$. $\sqrt{4}$ does not refer to 'a' solution to $x^2=4$, it refers to 'the positive' solution to that equation.

---

*Except in certain contexts, but I don't think this is one of them.

Comment: I think by $x = (2 \oplus -2)$ the OP meant the "exclusive or", i.e. 2 or -2 but not possibly both.

Comment: Sorry about the notation. I modified my post and it should be clearer now. Thanks!

Comment: @JagTalon: Okay sure. In that case my answer still applies. It is true that solving $x^2 = 4$ gives rise to an xor, since $x$ cannot take two values; but $\sqrt{4}$ takes just one value $-$ it is unambiguously equal to $2$.

Comment: @CliveN. Thanks for your answer! But what about the case where $x^2 = 0$ as Johannes mentioned? Would that make an inclusive-or?

Comment: @JagTalon: What do you think? ;)

Comment: @CliveN. I guess it would make an inclusive-or for 0, but an exclusive-or for any other real number. Thanks for helping me with logic!

Comment: @CliveN. I meant positive real numbers :D

Comment: @JagTalon: Well it can't be exclusive or for $0$, and to be honest it doesn't really need to be inclusive or either. If $x^2=0$ then $x=0$, end of, since $-0=0$. If you had $x=0$ xor $x=-0$ then it has to be false, since $x=0$ if and only if $x=-0$ :)

Comment: @CliveN. Ah yes, it does seem to be a bit excessive to write something like if $x^2 = 0$, then $x = 0 \vee x= -0$. Awesome!